# If group G is broken into 2 coset H and K, why is left coset of H equal to right coset of H?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading through explanations/proof in several texts but I'm stumped by the following explanations.  "If [G:H] = 2, then there are only 2 right cosets of H (H itself and complement of H).  Ditto for left cosets.  Therefore, left coset of H is equal to right coset of H."  WHY?  Still STUMPED!  FORGOT...H is a subgroup of H.

Comment: I suspect you are overthinking this.  All it is saying is that in the situation described, the right cosets are $H$ and $\overline H$, and the left cosets are $H$ and $\overline H$, the same.

Comment: In that case, why is left coset of H equal to right coset of H?

Comment: One right coset of $H$ is the *subgroup* $H$ itself. Similarly one left coset of $H$ is the subgroup $H$ itself. Therefore they are equal. Similarly, the other right coset and the other left coset are each the complement of $H$.

Comment: Because you know all the left cosets, and you know all the right cosets, and they are the same - just look at them.  Imagine you solve an equation and the solutions are $x=5$, $x=6$, and then you solve a completely different equation and you find the solutions are $x=5$, $x=6$.  Then you know that the solutions of the two equations are the same, just look at them.

Answer (score 0):

The cosets always form a partition of the group, i.e. if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $[G:H]=m$ and $g_1,\dots,g_m$ are a set of distinct coset representatives, then

$$G=\bigcup_{i=1}^m g_iH,$$

where this union is disjoint.

Now, take $m=[G:H]=2$, and then take any $g\in G\smallsetminus H$. We have

$$G=H\cup gH$$

where this union is disjoint. Hence, we get that $gH=G\smallsetminus H$.

However, the same exact argument works for right cosets, so for the same $g$ we have $Hg=G\smallsetminus H$, and in particular you get $gH=Hg$.